# Thread Pools ThreadStart and Finished Problem xamarin iOS

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, xamarin.ios, awss3transferutility

I am trying to download an XML file of size 85MB in my Xamarin iOS iPad App. Sometimes download completes successfully, but other times download hangs inbetween somewhere without giving any error. Progress stops.

**AWS SDK version:**

AWSSDK.S3 3.3.25.1

AWSSDK.Core 3.3.27.3

I tried both methods . Here is my code:

**1- GetObject**

```
            var  clientRequest = new AmazonS3Client(AWSAccessKey,
                                    AWSSecretKey,
                                        Amazon.RegionEndpoint.USEast1);
            try
            {
                GetObjectRequest request = new GetObjectRequest
                {
                    BucketName = AWSBucketName,
                    Key = Path + "File1.xml"
                };
                using (GetObjectResponse response = await clientRequest.GetObjectAsync(request))
                {
                 response.WriteObjectProgressEvent += displayDownloadProgress;
                 await response.WriteResponseStreamToFileAsync(destPath, false);                        
                }
            }
            catch (AmazonS3Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error encountered ***. Message:'{0}' when writing an object", e.Message);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Unknown encountered on server. Message:'{0}' when writing an object", e.Message);
            }
```

**2- TransferUtility**

```
            var utility = new TransferUtility(cas.AWSAccessKey,
                                cas.AWSSecretKey,
                                Amazon.RegionEndpoint.USEast1);

            TransferUtilityDownloadRequest dr = new TransferUtilityDownloadRequest();
            dr.BucketName = AWSBucketName;
            dr.Key = Path + "File1.xml";
            dr.FilePath = destPath;
            dr.WriteObjectProgressEvent += displayDownloadProgress;
            await utility.DownloadAsync(dr);



            public void displayDownloadProgress(object sender, WriteObjectProgressArgs args)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("Download Progress: " + (args.PercentDone));

                InvokeOnMainThread(() =>
                {
                    BTProgressHUD.ShowContinuousProgress("Download Progress: " + args.PercentDone.ToString() + "%", ProgressHUD.MaskType.Gradient);
                });

                if (args.PercentDone >= 100)
                {
                    BTProgressHUD.Dismiss();
                }
            }
```

I am attaching the Application OutPut Log also. Output log shows some problem with Threads. When threads start finishing between the download process, then download didn't complete successfully. But when there is no activity in the Thread, then Download complete successfully.

```
            --------------------------------------------------------------
            ---------------**LOG OF Successful DOWNLOAD**---------------------
            --------------------------------------------------------------

            Launched application 'com.companyname.TabbedView' on 'MyIpad’s iPad' with pid 217
            Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/7364EC69-75C0-4D2D-B40F-1E9FFF93671A/Navigation.app/Mono.Security.dll [External]
            Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/7364EC69-75C0-4D2D-B40F-1E9FFF93671A/Navigation.app/System.dll [External]
            Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/7364EC69-75C0-4D2D-B40F-1E9FFF93671A/Navigation.app/System.Core.dll [External]
            Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/7364EC69-75C0-4D2D-B40F-1E9FFF93671A/Navigation.app/Xamarin.iOS.dll [External]
            Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/7364EC69-75C0-4D2D-B40F-1E9FFF93671A/Navigation.app/PlaceholderEnabledUITextView.dll [External]
            Thread started:  #2
            Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/7364EC69-75C0-4D2D-B40F-1E9FFF93671A/Navigation.app/SignaturePad.dll [External]
            Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/7364EC69-75C0-4D2D-B40F-1E9FFF93671A/Navigation.app/BTProgressHUD.dll [External]
            Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/7364EC69-75C0-4D2D-B40F-1E9FFF93671A/Navigation.app/System.Net.Http.dll [External]
            Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/7364EC69-75C0-4D2D-B40F-1E9FFF93671A/Navigation.app/System.Xml.dll [External]
            Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/7364EC69-75C0-4D2D-B40F-1E9FFF93671A/Navigation.app/System.Numerics.dll [External]
            Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/7364EC69-75C0-4D2D-B40F-1E9FFF93671A/Navigation.app/System.ServiceModel.Internals.dll [External]
            Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/7364EC69-75C0-4D2D-B40F-1E9FFF93671A/Navigation.app/System.Runtime.Serialization.dll [External]
            Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/7364EC69-75C0-4D2D-B40F-1E9FFF93671A/Navigation.app/System.Transactions.dll [External]
            Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/7364EC69-75C0-4D2D-B40F-1E9FFF93671A/Navigation.app/System.Data.dll [External]
            Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/7364EC69-75C0-4D2D-B40F-1E9FFF93671A/Navigation.app/System.Xml.Linq.dll [External]
            Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/7364EC69-75C0-4D2D-B40F-1E9FFF93671A/Navigation.app/Newtonsoft.Json.dll [External]
            Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/7364EC69-75C0-4D2D-B40F-1E9FFF93671A/Navigation.app/PCLStorage.Abstractions.dll [External]
            Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/7364EC69-75C0-4D2D-B40F-1E9FFF93671A/Navigation.app/Validation.dll [External]
            Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/7364EC69-75C0-4D2D-B40F-1E9FFF93671A/Navigation.app/PInvoke.Windows.Core.dll [External]
            Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/7364EC69-75C0-4D2D-B40F-1E9FFF93671A/Navigation.app/PInvoke.Kernel32.dll [External]
            Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/7364EC69-75C0-4D2D-B40F-1E9FFF93671A/Navigation.app/PInvoke.BCrypt.dll [External]
            Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/7364EC69-75C0-4D2D-B40F-1E9FFF93671A/Navigation.app/PCLCrypto.dll [External]
            Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/7364EC69-75C0-4D2D-B40F-1E9FFF93671A/Navigation.app/PCLStorage.dll [External]
            Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/7364EC69-75C0-4D2D-B40F-1E9FFF93671A/Navigation.app/AWSSDK.Core.dll [External]
            Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/7364EC69-75C0-4D2D-B40F-1E9FFF93671A/Navigation.app/AWSSDK.S3.dll [External]
            Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/7364EC69-75C0-4D2D-B40F-1E9FFF93671A/Navigation.app/Navigation.exe
            Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/7364EC69-75C0-4D2D-B40F-1E9FFF93671A/Navigation.app/System.Runtime.dll [External]
            Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/7364EC69-75C0-4D2D-B40F-1E9FFF93671A/Navigation.app/netstandard.dll [External]
            Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/7364EC69-75C0-4D2D-B40F-1E9FFF93671A/Navigation.app/System.Threading.Tasks.dll [External]
            Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/7364EC69-75C0-4D2D-B40F-1E9FFF93671A/Navigation.app/System.IO.dll [External]
            Thread started:  #3
            Thread started: <Thread Pool> #4
            Thread started: <Thread Pool> #5
            Thread started: <Thread Pool> #6
            Thread started: <Thread Pool> #7
            Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/7364EC69-75C0-4D2D-B40F-1E9FFF93671A/Navigation.app/System.Net.Primitives.dll [External]
            Thread started: <Thread Pool> #8
            Thread finished: <Thread Pool> #5
            Thread finished: <Thread Pool> #6
            Thread started: <Thread Pool> #9
            Thread started: <Thread Pool> #10
            Thread started: <Thread Pool> #11
            Thread started: <Thread Pool> #12
            Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/7364EC69-75C0-4D2D-B40F-1E9FFF93671A/Navigation.app/System.Collections.dll [External]
            Resolved pending breakpoint at 'FacilitiesAndAuditsViewController.cs:703,27' to void Navigation.FacilitiesAndAuditsViewController.<DownloadFileFromS3>d__29.MoveNext () [0x0025a].
            Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/7364EC69-75C0-4D2D-B40F-1E9FFF93671A/Navigation.app/System.Text.RegularExpressions.dll [External]
            Thread finished: <Thread Pool> #4
            Thread started: <Thread Pool> #13
            Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/7364EC69-75C0-4D2D-B40F-1E9FFF93671A/Navigation.app/System.Threading.dll [External]
            Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/7364EC69-75C0-4D2D-B40F-1E9FFF93671A/Navigation.app/System.Net.Requests.dll [External]
            Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/7364EC69-75C0-4D2D-B40F-1E9FFF93671A/Navigation.app/System.Runtime.Extensions.dll [External]
            Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/7364EC69-75C0-4D2D-B40F-1E9FFF93671A/Navigation.app/System.Linq.dll [External]
            Thread started: <Thread Pool> #14
            Thread started: <Thread Pool> #15
            Thread started: <Thread Pool> #16
            Download Progress: 0
            Download Progress: 0
            Download Progress: 0
            Download Progress: 1
            Download Progress: 1
            Download Progress: 1
            Thread started: <Thread Pool> #4
            Thread started: <Thread Pool> #5
            Download Progress: 1
            Download Progress: 1
            Download Progress: 1
            Download Progress: 2
            Download Progress: 2
            Download Progress: 2
            Download Progress: 2
            Download Progress: 2
            Download Progress: 3
            Download Progress: 3
            Download Progress: 3
            Thread started: <Thread Pool> #6
            Download Progress: 3
            Download Progress: 3
            Download Progress: 4
            Download Progress: 4
            Download Progress: 4
            Download Progress: 4
            Download Progress: 5
            Download Progress: 5
            Download Progress: 5
            Download Progress: 5
            Download Progress: 6
            Download Progress: 6
            Download Progress: 6
            Download Progress: 6
            Download Progress: 7
            Download Progress: 7
            Download Progress: 7
            Download Progress: 8
            Download Progress: 8
            Download Progress: 8
            Download Progress: 8
            Download Progress: 9
            Download Progress: 9
            Download Progress: 9
            Download Progress: 9
            Download Progress: 10
            Download Progress: 10
            Download Progress: 10
            Download Progress: 10
            Download Progress: 11
            Download Progress: 11
            Download Progress: 11
            Download Progress: 11
            Download Progress: 12
            Download Progress: 12
            Download Progress: 12
            Download Progress: 12
            Download Progress: 13
            Download Progress: 13
            Download Progress: 13
            Download Progress: 13
            Download Progress: 13
            Download Progress: 14
            Download Progress: 14
            Download Progress: 14
            Download Progress: 15
            Download Progress: 15
            Download Progress: 15
            Thread finished: <Thread Pool> #13
            Thread started: <Thread Pool> #17
            Download Progress: 15
            Download Progress: 15
            Download Progress: 15
            Download Progress: 15
            Download Progress: 15
            Download Progress: 16
            Download Progress: 16
            Download Progress: 16
            Download Progress: 16
            Download Progress: 17
            Download Progress: 17
            Download Progress: 18
            Download Progress: 18
            Download Progress: 19
            Download Progress: 19
            Download Progress: 19
            Download Progress: 19
            Download Progress: 19
            Download Progress: 20
            Download Progress: 20
            Download Progress: 20
            Download Progress: 21
            Download Progress: 21
            Download Progress: 21
            Download Progress: 21
            Download Progress: 22
            Download Progress: 22
            Download Progress: 22
            Download Progress: 22
            Thread finished: <Thread Pool> #17
            Thread started: <Thread Pool> #18
            Download Progress: 22
            Download Progress: 22
            Download Progress: 23
            Download Progress: 23
            Download Progress: 23
            Download Progress: 23
            Download Progress: 24
            Download Progress: 24
            Download Progress: 24
            Download Progress: 25
            Download Progress: 25
            Download Progress: 25
            Download Progress: 25
            Download Progress: 26
            Download Progress: 26
            Download Progress: 26
            Download Progress: 26
            Download Progress: 27
            Download Progress: 27
            Download Progress: 27
            Download Progress: 27
            Download Progress: 28
            Download Progress: 28
            Download Progress: 28
            Download Progress: 28
            Download Progress: 28
            Download Progress: 29
            Download Progress: 29
            Download Progress: 29
            Download Progress: 29
            Download Progress: 30
            Download Progress: 30
            Download Progress: 30
            Download Progress: 30
            Download Progress: 31
            Download Progress: 31
            Download Progress: 31
            Download Progress: 31
            Download Progress: 32
            Download Progress: 32
            Download Progress: 32
            Download Progress: 32
            Download Progress: 33
            Download Progress: 33
            Download Progress: 33
            Download Progress: 34
            Download Progress: 34
            Download Progress: 34
            Download Progress: 35
            Download Progress: 35
            Download Progress: 35
            Download Progress: 35
            Download Progress: 35
            Download Progress: 36
            Download Progress: 36
            Download Progress: 36
            Download Progress: 36
            Download Progress: 37
            Download Progress: 37
            Download Progress: 38
            Download Progress: 38
            Download Progress: 38
            Download Progress: 38
            Thread finished: <Thread Pool> #18
            Thread started: <Thread Pool> #19
            Download Progress: 38
            Download Progress: 38
            Download Progress: 39
            Download Progress: 39
            Download Progress: 39
            Download Progress: 39
            Download Progress: 40
            Download Progress: 40
            Download Progress: 40
            Download Progress: 41
            Download Progress: 41
            Download Progress: 41
            Download Progress: 41
            Download Progress: 42
            Download Progress: 42
            Download Progress: 42
            Download Progress: 42
            Download Progress: 43
            Download Progress: 43
            Download Progress: 43
            Download Progress: 43
            Download Progress: 43
            Download Progress: 44
            Download Progress: 44
            Download Progress: 44
            Download Progress: 45
            Download Progress: 45
            Download Progress: 45
            Download Progress: 46
            Download Progress: 46
            Download Progress: 46
            Download Progress: 46
            Download Progress: 47
            Download Progress: 47
            Download Progress: 47
            Download Progress: 47
            Download Progress: 48
            Download Progress: 48
            Download Progress: 48
            Download Progress: 48
            Download Progress: 49
            Download Progress: 49
            Download Progress: 49
            Download Progress: 50
            Download Progress: 50
            Download Progress: 50
            Download Progress: 51
            Download Progress: 51
            Download Progress: 51
            Download Progress: 52
            Download Progress: 52
            Download Progress: 52
            Download Progress: 53
            Download Progress: 53
            Download Progress: 53
            Download Progress: 53
            Download Progress: 54
            Download Progress: 54
            Download Progress: 54
            Download Progress: 54
            Download Progress: 54
            Download Progress: 55
            Download Progress: 55
            Download Progress: 56
            Download Progress: 56
            Download Progress: 56
            Download Progress: 56
            Download Progress: 56
            Download Progress: 57
            Download Progress: 57
            Download Progress: 57
            Download Progress: 58
            Download Progress: 58
            Download Progress: 58
            Download Progress: 58
            Download Progress: 58
            Download Progress: 59
            Download Progress: 60
            Download Progress: 60
            Download Progress: 60
            Download Progress: 60
            Download Progress: 60
            Download Progress: 61
            Download Progress: 61
            Download Progress: 61
            Download Progress: 62
            Download Progress: 62
            Download Progress: 62
            Download Progress: 62
            Download Progress: 63
            Thread finished: <Thread Pool> #19
            Thread started: <Thread Pool> #17
            Download Progress: 63
            Download Progress: 63
            Download Progress: 63
            Download Progress: 64
            Download Progress: 64
            Download Progress: 64
            Download Progress: 65
            Download Progress: 65
            Download Progress: 65
            Download Progress: 66
            Download Progress: 66
            Download Progress: 66
            Download Progress: 67
            Download Progress: 67
            Download Progress: 67
            Download Progress: 68
            Download Progress: 68
            Download Progress: 68
            Download Progress: 69
            Download Progress: 69
            Download Progress: 69
            Download Progress: 69
            Download Progress: 70
            Download Progress: 70
            Download Progress: 70
            Download Progress: 71
            Download Progress: 71
            Download Progress: 71
            Download Progress: 71
            Download Progress: 72
            Download Progress: 73
            Download Progress: 73
            Download Progress: 73
            Download Progress: 73
            Download Progress: 74
            Download Progress: 74
            Download Progress: 74
            Download Progress: 75
            Download Progress: 75
            Download Progress: 75
            Download Progress: 76
            Download Progress: 76
            Download Progress: 76
            Download Progress: 77
            Download Progress: 77
            Download Progress: 77
            Download Progress: 77
            Download Progress: 78
            Download Progress: 78
            Download Progress: 78
            Download Progress: 79
            Download Progress: 79
            Download Progress: 79
            Download Progress: 79
            Download Progress: 79
            Download Progress: 79
            Download Progress: 80
            Download Progress: 80
            Download Progress: 80
            Download Progress: 81
            Download Progress: 81
            Download Progress: 81
            Download Progress: 81
            Download Progress: 82
            Download Progress: 82
            Download Progress: 82
            Download Progress: 82
            Download Progress: 83
            Download Progress: 83
            Download Progress: 83
            Download Progress: 83
            Download Progress: 84
            Download Progress: 84
            Download Progress: 84
            Download Progress: 85
            Download Progress: 85
            Download Progress: 85
            Download Progress: 85
            Download Progress: 86
            Download Progress: 86
            Download Progress: 86
            Download Progress: 87
            Download Progress: 87
            Download Progress: 87
            Download Progress: 88
            Download Progress: 88
            Download Progress: 88
            Download Progress: 88
            Download Progress: 89
            Download Progress: 90
            Download Progress: 90
            Download Progress: 91
            Download Progress: 91
            Download Progress: 91
            Download Progress: 92
            Download Progress: 92
            Download Progress: 92
            Download Progress: 92
            Download Progress: 93
            Download Progress: 93
            Download Progress: 93
            Download Progress: 93
            Download Progress: 93
            Download Progress: 94
            Download Progress: 94
            Download Progress: 94
            Download Progress: 95
            Download Progress: 95
            Download Progress: 95
            Download Progress: 96
            Download Progress: 96
            Download Progress: 96
            Download Progress: 97
            Download Progress: 97
            Download Progress: 97
            Download Progress: 97
            Download Progress: 98
            Download Progress: 99
            Download Progress: 99
            Download Progress: 99
            Download Progress: 99
            Download Progress: 99
            Download Progress: 99
            Download Progress: 100
            Thread finished: <Thread Pool> #17
            Thread started: <Thread Pool> #20
            Thread finished: <Thread Pool> #16
            Thread finished: <Thread Pool> #7

            --------------------------------------------------------------
            -----------------**LOG OF FAILED DOWNLOAD**-----------------------
            --------------------------------------------------------------

            Loaded assembly: /Users/muhammadbilal/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/70BDF9FF-14F8-4C1F-8C06-96A71E5D1987/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/786FD160-56DF-47F7-ABF1-D1FB403E5EA0/Navigation.app/Xamarin.iOS.dll [External]
            Thread started:  #2
            Loaded assembly: /Users/muhammadbilal/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/70BDF9FF-14F8-4C1F-8C06-96A71E5D1987/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/786FD160-56DF-47F7-ABF1-D1FB403E5EA0/Navigation.app/Navigation.exe
            Loaded assembly: /Users/muhammadbilal/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/70BDF9FF-14F8-4C1F-8C06-96A71E5D1987/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/786FD160-56DF-47F7-ABF1-D1FB403E5EA0/Navigation.app/System.dll [External]
            Loaded assembly: /Users/muhammadbilal/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/70BDF9FF-14F8-4C1F-8C06-96A71E5D1987/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/786FD160-56DF-47F7-ABF1-D1FB403E5EA0/Navigation.app/AWSSDK.S3.dll [External]
            Loaded assembly: /Users/muhammadbilal/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/70BDF9FF-14F8-4C1F-8C06-96A71E5D1987/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/786FD160-56DF-47F7-ABF1-D1FB403E5EA0/Navigation.app/PlaceholderEnabledUITextView.dll [External]
            Loaded assembly: /Users/muhammadbilal/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/70BDF9FF-14F8-4C1F-8C06-96A71E5D1987/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/786FD160-56DF-47F7-ABF1-D1FB403E5EA0/Navigation.app/System.Xml.dll [External]
            Loaded assembly: /Users/muhammadbilal/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/70BDF9FF-14F8-4C1F-8C06-96A71E5D1987/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/786FD160-56DF-47F7-ABF1-D1FB403E5EA0/Navigation.app/SignaturePad.dll [External]
            Loaded assembly: /Users/muhammadbilal/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/70BDF9FF-14F8-4C1F-8C06-96A71E5D1987/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/786FD160-56DF-47F7-ABF1-D1FB403E5EA0/Navigation.app/Mono.Security.dll [External]
            Loaded assembly: /Users/muhammadbilal/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/70BDF9FF-14F8-4C1F-8C06-96A71E5D1987/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/786FD160-56DF-47F7-ABF1-D1FB403E5EA0/Navigation.app/AWSSDK.Core.dll [External]
            Loaded assembly: /Users/muhammadbilal/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/70BDF9FF-14F8-4C1F-8C06-96A71E5D1987/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/786FD160-56DF-47F7-ABF1-D1FB403E5EA0/Navigation.app/System.Core.dll [External]
            Loaded assembly: /Users/muhammadbilal/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/70BDF9FF-14F8-4C1F-8C06-96A71E5D1987/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/786FD160-56DF-47F7-ABF1-D1FB403E5EA0/Navigation.app/System.Net.Http.dll [External]
            Loaded assembly: /Users/muhammadbilal/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/70BDF9FF-14F8-4C1F-8C06-96A71E5D1987/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/786FD160-56DF-47F7-ABF1-D1FB403E5EA0/Navigation.app/PCLCrypto.dll [External]
            Loaded assembly: /Users/muhammadbilal/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/70BDF9FF-14F8-4C1F-8C06-96A71E5D1987/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/786FD160-56DF-47F7-ABF1-D1FB403E5EA0/Navigation.app/PInvoke.BCrypt.dll [External]
            Loaded assembly: /Users/muhammadbilal/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/70BDF9FF-14F8-4C1F-8C06-96A71E5D1987/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/786FD160-56DF-47F7-ABF1-D1FB403E5EA0/Navigation.app/PInvoke.Windows.Core.dll [External]
            Loaded assembly: /Users/muhammadbilal/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/70BDF9FF-14F8-4C1F-8C06-96A71E5D1987/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/786FD160-56DF-47F7-ABF1-D1FB403E5EA0/Navigation.app/PInvoke.Kernel32.dll [External]
            Loaded assembly: /Users/muhammadbilal/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/70BDF9FF-14F8-4C1F-8C06-96A71E5D1987/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/786FD160-56DF-47F7-ABF1-D1FB403E5EA0/Navigation.app/System.Numerics.dll [External]
            Loaded assembly: /Users/muhammadbilal/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/70BDF9FF-14F8-4C1F-8C06-96A71E5D1987/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/786FD160-56DF-47F7-ABF1-D1FB403E5EA0/Navigation.app/Validation.dll [External]
            Loaded assembly: /Users/muhammadbilal/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/70BDF9FF-14F8-4C1F-8C06-96A71E5D1987/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/786FD160-56DF-47F7-ABF1-D1FB403E5EA0/Navigation.app/System.Xml.Linq.dll [External]
            Loaded assembly: /Users/muhammadbilal/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/70BDF9FF-14F8-4C1F-8C06-96A71E5D1987/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/786FD160-56DF-47F7-ABF1-D1FB403E5EA0/Navigation.app/System.Runtime.Serialization.dll [External]
            Loaded assembly: /Users/muhammadbilal/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/70BDF9FF-14F8-4C1F-8C06-96A71E5D1987/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/786FD160-56DF-47F7-ABF1-D1FB403E5EA0/Navigation.app/PCLStorage.Abstractions.dll [External]
            Loaded assembly: /Users/muhammadbilal/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/70BDF9FF-14F8-4C1F-8C06-96A71E5D1987/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/786FD160-56DF-47F7-ABF1-D1FB403E5EA0/Navigation.app/PCLStorage.dll [External]
            Loaded assembly: /Users/muhammadbilal/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/70BDF9FF-14F8-4C1F-8C06-96A71E5D1987/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/786FD160-56DF-47F7-ABF1-D1FB403E5EA0/Navigation.app/BTProgressHUD.dll [External]
            Loaded assembly: /Users/muhammadbilal/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/70BDF9FF-14F8-4C1F-8C06-96A71E5D1987/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/786FD160-56DF-47F7-ABF1-D1FB403E5EA0/Navigation.app/Newtonsoft.Json.dll [External]
            Loaded assembly: /Users/muhammadbilal/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/70BDF9FF-14F8-4C1F-8C06-96A71E5D1987/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/786FD160-56DF-47F7-ABF1-D1FB403E5EA0/Navigation.app/System.Data.dll [External]
            Thread started: <Thread Pool> #3
            Thread started: <Thread Pool> #4
            Thread started: <Thread Pool> #5
            Thread started: <Thread Pool> #6
            Resolved pending breakpoint at 'FacilitiesAndAuditsViewController.cs:715,27' to void Navigation.FacilitiesAndAuditsViewController.<DownloadFileFromS3>d__29.MoveNext () [0x0025a].
            Thread started:  #7
            Thread started: <Thread Pool> #8
            Thread started: <Thread Pool> #9
            Thread started: <Thread Pool> #10
            Thread finished: <Thread Pool> #10
            Thread finished: <Thread Pool> #4
            Thread finished: <Thread Pool> #9
            Thread finished: <Thread Pool> #5
            Thread finished: <Thread Pool> #6
            Thread finished: <Thread Pool> #3
            Thread started: <Thread Pool> #12
            Thread started: <Thread Pool> #13
            Thread started: <Thread Pool> #14
            Thread started: <Thread Pool> #15
            Thread started: <Thread Pool> #16
            Thread started: <Thread Pool> #17
            Thread started: <Thread Pool> #18
            Thread started: <Thread Pool> #19
            Thread started: <Thread Pool> #20
            Thread started: <Thread Pool> #21
            Thread started: <Thread Pool> #22
            Download Progress: 0
            Thread started: <Thread Pool> #9
            Download Progress: 0
            Download Progress: 0
            Download Progress: 0
            Download Progress: 0
            Thread started: <Thread Pool> #23
            Thread started: <Thread Pool> #24
            Download Progress: 0
            Download Progress: 0
            Download Progress: 1
            Download Progress: 1
            Download Progress: 1
            Download Progress: 1
            Download Progress: 1
            Download Progress: 1
            Download Progress: 1
            Download Progress: 1
            Download Progress: 2
            Download Progress: 2
            Download Progress: 2
            Download Progress: 2
            Download Progress: 2
            Download Progress: 2
            Download Progress: 2
            Download Progress: 2
            Download Progress: 3
            Download Progress: 3
            Download Progress: 3
            Download Progress: 3
            Download Progress: 3
            Download Progress: 3
            Download Progress: 3
            Download Progress: 3
            Download Progress: 4
            Download Progress: 4
            Download Progress: 4
            Download Progress: 4
            Download Progress: 4
            Thread started: <Thread Pool> #25
            Thread started: <Thread Pool> #26
            Download Progress: 4
            Download Progress: 4
            Download Progress: 4
            Download Progress: 5
            Download Progress: 5
            Download Progress: 5
            Download Progress: 5
            Download Progress: 5
            Download Progress: 5
            Thread finished: <Thread Pool> #9
            Thread finished: <Thread Pool> #14
            Thread finished: <Thread Pool> #25
            Thread finished: <Thread Pool> #13
            Thread finished: <Thread Pool> #17
            Thread finished: <Thread Pool> #26
            Thread finished: <Thread Pool> #23
            Thread finished: <Thread Pool> #15
            Thread finished: <Thread Pool> #22
            Thread finished: <Thread Pool> #16
            Thread finished: <Thread Pool> #12
            Thread started: <Thread Pool> #27
            Thread finished: <Thread Pool> #19
            Thread finished: <Thread Pool> #18
            Thread started: <Thread Pool> #13
            Thread started: <Thread Pool> #28
            Thread finished: <Thread Pool> #27
            Thread started: <Thread Pool> #14
            Thread finished: <Thread Pool> #13
            Thread finished: <Thread Pool> #28
            Thread finished: <Thread Pool> #14
            Thread started: <Thread Pool> #15
            Thread finished: <Thread Pool> #20
            Thread started: <Thread Pool> #29
            Thread started: <Thread Pool> #13
            Thread finished: <Thread Pool> #29
            Thread finished: <Thread Pool> #15
            Thread started: <Thread Pool> #14
            -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
            -------NOTHING IS HAPPENING AFTER THIS LAST LINE. APPLICATION IS STILL-------------
            -------------NOTHING ELSE IS COMING IN THE APPLCATION OUTPUT WINDOW----------------
            -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```